# Allure Framework: How to fail only one step in the test method

Tags: unit-testing, frameworks, report, automated-tests, allure

Does anyone know, how to fail only one step in the test and allow the test finish all steps, using Allure framework!

For exemple, I have one test wich consists of 3 test steps, and each of the steps has it's own assertion. It can look like this:

```
@Test
public void test() 
    step1();
    step2();
    step3();
}

@Step
public void step1() {
    Assert.assertEquals(1, 0);
}

@Step
public void step2() {
    Assert.assertEquals(1, 1);
}

@Step
public void step3() {
    Assert.assertEquals(2, 2);
}
```

When step1 fail, then test method will fail too. Is there a possibility to finish other two steps with their own assertions and not fail the test? Like TestNG does with SoftAssert. (org.testng.asserts.SoftAssert)

And as a result I would like to see the report where we can see all broken and passed test steps,(in one test method) like in 1.4.9 Allure release https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core/releases/tag/allure-core-1.4.9 on the picture report.

Comment: +1 - this is important especially when you check several field - you should know all incorrect data (all fields) and not to do "bug fix >> rerun test" for each field. It is much better to collect more information during single test run.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can, but **you shouldn't**. You're breaking the concept of a test. A test is something that either passes or fails with a description of a failure. It is not something that can partially fail.

When you write a test you should include only those assertions that are bound to each other. Like if the first assertion fails, then the second is not needed by your functionality at all. That means if you have assertions that are not dependent on each other – you better make a couple of test methods and they will be completely separated and will fail separately.

In short, the test should not continue after a failed step and that's it. Otherwise – it's a bad test.

P.S. That's why JUnit does not allow soft assertions.

P.P.S If you reallyreallyreally need to check all the three things – possible workaround is using an [ErrorCollector](http://junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/rules/ErrorCollector.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Yes you are absolutely right about concept of a test, 
but what if I need to break this concept?

For instance:
After clicking button 'submit' on the registration form
and I want to know what data appeared in following tables:
 - clients; 
 - users; 
 - accounts;
 - and so on...
 and the order is also important
 In this case softAssert can show me the whole "picture"
 
Unfortunately, using ErrorCollerctor with Allure shows only the last error in the Allure  report, but no fails the test :)

Is there other approach to fail only one step in the test?

Answer (score 0):

The approach you are looking for is called "soft asserts".
If you are using TestNG you can do it like this:

```
SoftAssert softAssert = new SoftAssert();
softAssert.assertEquals(true, myBoolean, "comment");
softAssert.assertEquals(1, myNumber, "comment");
softAssert.assertAll();
```

For JUnit5:

```
Assertions.assertAll(
   () -> assertTrue(myBoolean, "myExplanationMessage"),
   () -> assertNotNull(myObject, "myExplanationMessage")
);
```

If you are testing a UI using the Selenide framework and want some `SelenideElement.should()`-like methods to not interrupt the test, you can do it like this:

```
Configuration.assertionMode = AssertionMode.SOFT;
.....
<your should(Condition)-like methods, which should not stop the test execution>
.....
Configuration.assertionMode = AssertionMode.STRICT;
```

---

I'm new to autotesting and not sure if it's a good practice or not, but I came across a test script where it came in handy. I made a test that can check both product names and prices on each page using just one loop through the page numbers.